# How to permute rows of a given matrix

Tags: r

Good morning !

Assume we have the following matrix :

```
m=matrix(1:18,ncol=2)
print("m : before")
print(m)

[1] "m : before"
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1   10
 [2,]    2   11
 [3,]    3   12
 [4,]    4   13
 [5,]    5   14
 [6,]    6   15
 [7,]    7   16
 [8,]    8   17
 [9,]    9   18
```

As an example, I'm wanting to permute a number of rows :

```
tmp=m[8:9,]
m[8:9,]=m[3:4,]
m[3:4,]=tmp
```

This is the same as :

```
# indices to permute 
before=8:9
after=3:4

tmp=m[before,]
m[before,]=m[after,]
m[after,]=tmp


[1] "after"
     [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1   10
 [2,]    2   11
 [3,]    8   17
 [4,]    9   18
 [5,]    5   14
 [6,]    6   15
 [7,]    7   16
 [8,]    3   12
 [9,]    4   13
```

I'm wanting to know if there is any package that automatize such task. For the moment , I'm not willing to use a user-defined function.

Thank you for help !

Comment: I might be missing something, but this seems like a trivial process to look for a package for. Functions in packages are udfs, just other users'.

Comment: Where does the permutation come from?  Do you want to specify it explicitly as in the question, or randomly permute?  @Elia's answer is just what you need for the random case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is just to use `base` r function, like `sample`:

```
set.seed(4)
m[sample(1:nrow(m),nrow(m)),]
```

which give you:

```
  [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    8   17
 [2,]    3   12
 [3,]    9   18
 [4,]    7   16
 [5,]    4   13
 [6,]    6   15
 [7,]    2   11
 [8,]    1   10
 [9,]    5   14
```

If you want to permute just some rows you can do :

```
m[7:9,] <- m[sample(7:9,3),]#where the last number (3) is the number of row 
to permute
```

which give you

```
   [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1   10
 [2,]    2   11
 [3,]    3   12
 [4,]    4   13
 [5,]    5   14
 [6,]    6   15
 [7,]    7   16
 [8,]    9   18
 [9,]    8   17
```

Comment: Sample's default size is the length of its first argument, so the example could be simplified to `m[7:9,] <- m[sample(7:9),]`

Answer (score 1):

Just try to exchange the index order.

```
m[c(before,after),] = m[c(after,before),]
```

Comment: I think this is the more elegant solution ! Thank you a lot